# Poetry install pytest but it is not in the pyproject.toml

Tags: python-poetry

I am little by little getting used to use Poetry (after years with Conda) and there is something that I just found.

I use `poetry add` to add `bagpy`. So now in the `pyproject.toml` there is an item for bagpy in the dependencies.

However installing bagpy installed also `pytest`. I checked it is installed and I can see it also in the `poetry.lock`.

However it does not appear in the `pyproject.toml`.

Can someone comment on this?

What is the purpose of `pyproject.toml` then?. What would happen if I add `pytest` by itself? Would that break bagpy?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is actually because, unlike compiled languages, like Java, `python` by default doesn't have an API only library, where the actual dependency is excluded from the installed package.

In your case, `pytest` is coming from `bagpy` because `bagpy` declares it as a dependency as can be seen in their [requirements.txt](https://github.com/jmscslgroup/bagpy/blob/master/requirements.txt)

`poetry` has a nice little feature called `development` dependencies, you can read about different dependency groups in their docs. These dependencies are not exported with the application. However, since `bagpy` is using a `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`, it doesn't have this feature.

You can also use `poetry show pytest` to see which of your dependencies requires `pytest`.